# Docker container does not run on macOS

Tags: macos, docker

I'm building the most basic container and trying to run it on macOS Big Sur 11.4 (Intel i9  processor). Docker Desktop version is 3.4.0 (3.4.0.5223). The Dockerfile has only:

`FROM i386/ubuntu:18.04`

Running `docker build -t test:v1 .` finished successfully.
However running the container: `docker run test:v1` produced the following error:

> WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/386) does not match the detected host platform (linux/amd64) and no specific platform was requested

Comment: The error is pretty clear, I'd say. You are trying to run a 32-bit image (i386) on a 64-bit architecture .

Comment: Yes, that was intentional. The app I will eventually run inside this container requires a 32-bit environment in order to run. Can this be done?

Comment: Docker itself doesn't deal with hardware emulation, though the macOS implementation necessarily includes a Linux VM since Docker is built on top of a Linux API. I don't know if there's a way to configure the underlying VM in Docker Desktop that's easier than just using something like Parallels or VirtualBox to run a 32-bit VM in the first place.

Comment: This question is probably more suitable for apple.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this is possible. One can build a container that will run on multiple CPU architectures and word size. I received the [answer](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-container-does-not-run-on-macos/111671) from Alex Hokanson on the Docker team.